# Policies regarding to "extended preprint" versions of papers

Tags: copyright, preprint

I want to publish a paper I wrote as a preprint. Anyhow, the paper in its original form has 12 pages (let's call that "version A"). Version A anyhow was rejected, so I compiled a reviewed version for another conference (IEEE) with 10 pages (version B). Here, the paper got accepted as a short paper, requiring it to be shortened to 8 pages (version C), being the camera ready version to be published (non-open access).

Because a lot of content had to be left out in version C, I want to publish the original version A as a preprint. Anyhow, I am not sure how this works in terms of the preprint conditions of IEEE.

In https://www.ieee.org/content/dam/ieee-org/ieee/web/org/pubs/author_faq.pdf, IEEE defines a differentiation of an "accepted manuscript" and a "published version" of papers:

- "Version B" is the "accepted manuscript"
- "Version C" is the "published version"

Now, version A is not exactly part of this definition. If at all, it might be seen as a precursor (or extension) of the accepted manuscript.

Besides adding the link to the published version in the preprint, what do I need to do to not run into any problems with copyright when publishing version A on arXiv? Also, must I or may I change the title, indicating that this is a preprint version?

Edit:

My questions are for IEEE published papers:

- What conditions for preprint publishing apply to a paper version that is different from "accepted manuscript" and "published version"?
- Can a preprint's title differ from the published version?

Comment: I believe you are asking too many questions at the same time. As for the "can I publish this", I believe https://v2.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/ does a great job at boiling down what's allowed for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The linked page anyhow does not specify any of this - or related - information. Regarding to the questions asked, I updated my original question.

Comment: "I want to publish the original version A as a preprint. Anyhow, I am not sure how this works in terms of the preprint conditions of IEEE." Sherpa includes what you can do with the submitted version (cf. [for LMCS](https://v2.sherpa.ac.uk/id/publication/21792) for instance), I thought this would help. Sorry if it didn't.

Comment: Thank you for the new link. The other one simply led to a landing page. Question still remains what applies to the mentioned version that is NOT an "accepted" oder "published" version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following advice from the IEEE copyright support center regarding to these questions (I'll paraphrase):

"Use either of the two following approaches:
a) post it as a regular preprint following the "accepted version" guidelines
b) post the longer version as a "version 1" and the accepted manuscript (8 page) as "version 2" using the versioning functionality for preprints at ArXiv or TechRxiv"